`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` not working with `ConstraintLayout`
I'm creating an Android application in Java using Android Studio, and I use a ConstraintLayout for the positioning of the views in my layout. The problem is that when I open the keyboard, it hide the EditText on the bottom by being over it.
I added the android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" argument to the <activity> tag in my manifest, but it didn't worked.
I tried also to add it programmatically using getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE) in the Java code of the activity but it still doesnt worked.
And I tried to wrap the ConstraintLayout in a ScrollView but it mess all the positioning.
My code:

AndroidManifest.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>


activity_main.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/command_input_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/terminal_padding"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/terminal_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/terminal_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/terminal_output"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:typeface="monospace"
            android:textSize="@dimen/terminal_text_size" />

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/command_input_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/command_input_label"
            android:labelFor="@id/command_input"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/terminal_padding"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/terminal_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/terminal_padding"
            android:text="@string/command_input_label"
            android:contentDescription="@string/command_input_label_contentDescription"
            android:typeface="monospace"
            android:textSize="@dimen/terminal_text_size" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/command_input"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:padding="@dimen/terminal_padding"
            android:typeface="monospace"
            android:textSize="@dimen/terminal_text_size"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/command_input_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/terminal_text_size"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/command_input_label_contentDescription"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/terminal_padding"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/terminal_padding"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/terminal_padding"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


MainActivity.java:

package net.author.myapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });

        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

        TextView terminalOutput = findViewById(R.id.terminal_output);
        EditText commandInput = findViewById(R.id.command_input);
        ScrollView scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
        ImageButton commandInputButton = findViewById(R.id.command_input_button);

        String welcome_message = String.format(getString(R.string.welcome_message), Build.VERSION.RELEASE, Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, Build.ID);

        terminalOutput.setText(welcome_message);
        commandInput.requestFocus();

        commandInputButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String command = commandInput.getText().toString();

            terminalOutput.append(getString(R.string.command_input_label) + command + "\n");
            terminalOutput.append(executeCommand(command));

            scrollView.post(() -> scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN));

            commandInput.setText("");
            commandInput.requestFocus();
        });
    }

    private String executeCommand(String command) {
        // Do something
    }
}


I tested your code locally, and the EditText isn’t covered by the keyboard when it opens. Can you clarify the exact issue you're facing?


For me it doesn't resize. Just wait because I changed it to ajustPan temporarily so it don't cover but when I was with the code that I provided it covered it. I can't use ajustPan as a definitive solution since it hide the top of the screen.
I think the problem is that it needs to be compatible with a wide range of Android versions, and I tested it not on the last version.
